# Warframe Network Communication

Tags: game-hacking, networking, api-reversing

Warframe is a MMO that has both servers and peer to peer networking, I am looking into the server side of things. What I am wanting to achieve is client communication to a emulated server.

So far I am sending files to the launcher via host domain redirecting and emulating content.warframe.com, this allows me to run the game on older versions so I don't got to worry about constantly updating and changing to make the new builds.

This allows for the play button to be usable and launch the actual game, which makes calls to api.warframe.com. This call uses tls 1.2 - 1.3, to counter act this I have made my own certification chain to make a certificate that claims to be api.warframe.com. I then installed the root certification authority (CA) of the chain into my windows Trusted Root Certificate Authorities.

Which leads to the issue I am stuck at. Warframe doesn't trust the certificate, self signed error code. This has me confused as I cant find any certificate pinning on the exe even more confusing is it's a 64 bit process yet makes the secure calls via ws2_32.dll send and recv functions. Nothing there to inform me of where it is storing it's own certificate store.

I have tried looking for answers on how to get past this road block and have came up with nothing, so now I ask directly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A little bit more information is that the game might use openssl as it has the eula in the game directory and a dedicated folder holding only the eula, I know for a fact it uses oodle as the log loads oo2net_9_win64 and oo2core_9_win64 dlls.

Comment: Have you checked if your certificate works at all e.g. in Edge?

Comment: Yes, I have tested in chrome and internet explorer. Both accept the certification as valid and allow https protocol without any warnings.